# No head block in fork db, perhaps we need to replay error at startup

Tags: nodeos

When I tempt to start nodeos using this command:

> nodeos --delete-all-blocks --genesis-json genesis.json --plugin eosio::chain_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin

almost everything goes correct except for one line that I paid attention to recently. It says:

> 2018-11-01T00:17:03.006 thread-0   controller.cpp:1380           startup              ] No head block in fork db, perhaps we need to replay

This line shows in red. I noticed there's an open [issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3152) on this exact error that at the end asked to write any further question to here. Any help?

Comment: Did you try a replay?

Comment: I get the same error. Did you soved this error.

Comment: @xiuyoung Nope :(

Answer (score 0):

Append --hard-replay to replay

Comment: Adding that doesn't do anything, everything (including the error) stays the same.

Comment: and --mongodb-wipe --hard-replay-blockchain ?
Delete your nodeos 'state' folder as well, if that doesn't work, delete also your blocks folder. You can find the state folder using $ sudo find / -name state

Comment: I added --mongodb-wipe --hard-replay-blockchain, deleted state and blocks folder, but the error still pops up. The server starts anyways, but I'm not sure how much does this error affects the server later.